Differences in the epistemological description and meaning of Plank length & Plank time and the discretization of spacetime
Why does there seem to be a schism between discreteness and continuity of space and time and even in the scientific setting why isn't there a clear explanation as to what the Planck length and time signifies.
I have been trying to research for the limits of size of our universe and I know what the upper limit is and how it is dictated but it seems to me that the lower limit seems to have a large dilemma among people both in the field of Science and the general public.
I have read remarks from some knowledgeable people that, "The Plank length is to space just like Absolute Zero is to temperature as there is no smaller region of space that would measure less than this amount of space", but is this the right definition it should have as pertaining to physical space.
And now I want to know why there seems to be such a discord between the two sides i.e., one side that claims that the Planck length is the least amount of space that is available in reality and there is no size below this length and claiming a sort of 'pixelization of the universe' at the Plank length limit and the other side that claims that the Plank length does not mean that the universe is pixelized and limited it's just that we don't have the access and the ability to measure it within the current bounds of technology.
Now, I really want to know why there seems to be a great epistemological divide in this topic. Mind you I have searched on this topic, from casual sources like YouTube, Physics forums (both Physics SE, Physics forums and AskPhysics on reddit) and I have also looked into scientific theories, models and consecutively scientific journals and this schism seems to hold no matter where I go.
One really interesting crux point I have heard is the fact that trying to measure a distance of anything smaller than a Planck length will actually open a tiny black hole in space and will devoid us from obtaining any information from that region of space but just because we can't observe that region of space doesn't mean it is there, right? Not having measurement and observation doesn't necessarily object a small region of space from existing, right? I feel like this is a sound logical position to hold.
TL;DR: Is there any logical reason to think that space itself is discretely measured? Wouldn't there be a lot of problems that would arise if space was discretized?

This question belongs in physics. stackexchange.com.

@DavidGudeman I don't think physics will entertain the reasoning of my argument at all.

I was banned from the physics stax for asking reasonable, highly mathematical questions. Your question wouldn't last 5 minutes.

@Miss_Understands My question is highly philosophical and not mathematical at all. I wonder even if it will last a minute even. I might even get banned for all i know.

You mean to say the Planck units are limitations of science, physics to be precise and possess no ontological import as to how the universe actually is? A matter of pixel resolution, as in if 2 objects were closer than the Planck distance, we would need to treat the 2 as 1? :D. Two stones tied together fall as 1, oui?

@Hudjefa Yes, somebody who finally understands and put my whole nonsensical spew to a beautiful one sentence. This is exactly what I am saying, I don't think Plank units possess any ontological meaning.

As for if 2 objects were closer than the planck distance they would still be 2 objects not one like a lot of other people say and mention.

@Howwhye, glad I could be of assistance. I do remember making a note of the possibility that something bad happens to the equations of physics at lengths smaller than the Planck length (re dividing by 0 in math).

There is no 'schism'. The significance of the Planck length is well understood by experts in the relevant aspects of theoretical physics and it is poorly understood by lots of other people. A poor understanding of a topic, sadly, has never been a barrier to publishing opinions on it- that is true in virtually every field, not just physics, so you will always find apparently conflicting statements that purport to be the truth. Pop science is full of them.
The Planck length was initially proposed by Planck purely as a unit of length, with none of the connotations about being any sort of absolute minimum length, all of that coming later. Apart from its tiny size, what makes the Planck length differ from other units of length, such as the furlong, the metre, the nautical mile and so on, is that it is defined as a ratio between fundamental constants in the Universe, rather than being some arbitrary definition invented for convenience by humans.
All of the claims you read about the Planck length being some pixel size for spacetime, etc, are oversimplified misinterpretations of the following. You might have heard that massive objects bend spacetime- well, all objects do, even photons, but on everyday scales the curvature they produce is entirely negligible. However, if you try to apply the equations of general relativity and quantum theory at very small scales, you find that the predicted curvature produced by photons becomes so significant that the everyday concept of length breaks down. There is no hard cut-off at the Planck length- things just get worse as you zoom in.

Thank you for such a great answer! You always have been helpful and accurate in your responses. It just frustrates me when people say there is a limit to how far one can zoom like "what?!" "how do you know?!" is there any philosophical or scientific reason why one would think otherwise, we have seen with the advent of science we are able to identify further smaller particles, this just means there is a lot more to know and for what we know the scale we can zoom in might be infinite. I just wish a lot more people would interact with my post and respond.

And thank you for being an appreciative reader!!!
